# APIM in consumption mode - get Azure APIM health check via /status-0123456789abcdef returns "Resource not found"

Tags: azure-api-management

We have created a new API-M in **Consumption** mode and cannot get health check via /status-0123456789abcdef to work. Anyone succeeded to get this to work?

https://bla-bla.azure-api.net*/status-0123456789abcdef*

I get: Resource not found

{ "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }

Answer (score 0):

This endpoint is not available in Consumption SKU. You can create your own API with operation to ping and see if it returns success or not to monitor service state. Be warned though that such calls will eat into free API calls budget.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! I'd get the same problem and after added in azure portal API for this route, everything worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you open the Application Insights resource that is associated to your consumption-based APIM instance in the Azure Portal. Then open the 'Availability' blade under 'Investigate'. You will see where a default availability test is configured, using the /status-0123456789abcdef endpoint. To fix the issue, it looks like you can delete, disable, or update the availability test to hit a valid endpoint. From what I can tell, Application Insights sets this up automatically when you associate it to your APIM instance.

Here is a link to the MS docs for configuring the availability tests:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability

[Availability Test Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkjiZ.jpg)